# Open this page in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to make a web page so that it opens in a specific tab when it is opened from a hyperlink?  Ideally with a given target name.

If one has control over the calling page(s) that link to the site, it's possible to specify the `_target` attribute  `<a href="https://mypage.com/resource/{{id}}" _target="{{id}}"`

In this case, is it possible for the destination page `https://mypage.com/resource/{{id}}` to say "I'd like to open in a new tab with this specific target" regardless from where it's linked to?

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer someone most likely will give you and it deals with things like: users have the ability to say how new links open in their settings for a browser and javascript can't override that.

Comment: That is not how the browser works and users are not used to that. Even if you manage to do it somehow, your users will find it odd. They have learned how to use the browser and they will find it really odd if you did that. Perhaps explain why you are doing that and tag your question with UX, I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not achieve this functionality from javascript.

However this can be achieved by message passing using browser extension.

Browser extension with proper permission to access tabs you can inject dynamic code.

But this can not be achieved just from javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best you can do, open in a new window. I typically have to do this when using an API or something that doesn't allow for use in anything but the Chrome browser, so I use a link to open in chrome.

Using something like:

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
window.open(url);
```

Comment: This creates the effect .. opens this page in new tab with defined target, and send this back one    `window.open(window.location.href, "MYTARGET"); window.history.back();`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't quite override other tabs, if that's what you're asking.
You can, however, open your link in a fresh tab like this:

```
    <a href="http://www.mypage.com/" target="_blank">
```

If you really need to, you can look into using cookies, but that's somewhat difficult to use in this situation.